# how to implement horizontally scrolling tabs using latest design library of android?

Tags: android, tabs, material-design

I want to implement material design scrolling tabs using latest design library.

As android developer blog says that it can be implemented with design library.

[See Android Blog Tab section](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/search?updated-max=2015-06-01T12:51:00-07:00&max-results=7)

It says  " ...as well as scrollable tabs... "

So how?

Comment: You really should describe **your** problem. Post a small example of what you have tried and what you want to acheive with it.

Comment: I am new and have NO credit to post images. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need!

```
     private void setUpTabs() {
            TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
            tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_SCROLLABLE);
        }
```